# How to gracefully exit a JXA script on error?

Tags: javascript-automation

I'm launching the myScript.js from terminal with:

```
osascript -l 'JavaScript' myScript.js
```

This is myScript.js:

```
"use strict";

var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

var curlOutPath = "/Users/dev/curl_output.json";

try {
  const data = app.read(curlOutPath);
  const parsed = JSON.parse(data);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(“1. Exit Here.”);
}

console.log(“2. This line should not execute.”);
```

I want to exit the script in the catch block.  I've tried "return;", "exit;", "quit;" and they all don't work.  I know JXA is poorly supported, so I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone knows the right keyword to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ObjC bridge

```
ObjC.import('stdlib')
$.exit(0)
```

Info [here](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/Shell-and-CLI-Interactions#setting-exit-code)

Comment: Although your answer _may_ be technically correct, you should back your assertions up with some commentary about _why_ it is happening, perhaps lifted (with proper attribution) from the link you inserted. Secondly, 'link-only' answers frequently get deleted because of the tendency for links to go dead at some time in the future.